# Flip linear-gradient when scrolling

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm using a linear-gradient with a 45 degree angle, but when I scroll down I would like it to flip, instead of just repeating, so that the colors match.

This is what I have now;

```css
body {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background: rgb(253, 41, 123);
      background: linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        rgba(253, 41, 123, 1) 0%,
        rgba(255, 88, 100, 1) 47%,
        rgba(255, 101, 91, 1) 100%
      );
    }
    
    
    div {
      height: 1500px;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Can anyone help me? TIA!

Comment: can you share a full working code with the scrolling your are talking about

Comment: @TemaniAfif I just edited the code snippet. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea using `mask` where the trick is to create two different layer with opposite gradient and mask will create alternate "holes" to see the bottom one:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background: rgb(253, 41, 123);
  background: 
    linear-gradient( to top right, rgba(253, 41, 123, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 88, 100, 1) 47%, rgba(255, 101, 91, 1) 100%) 
    0 0/100% 100vh;
}

html::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( to bottom right, rgba(253, 41, 123, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 88, 100, 1) 47%, rgba(255, 101, 91, 1) 100%) 
    0 0/100% 100vh;
  -webkit-mask: repeating-linear-gradient(transparent 0 100vh, #fff 0 200vh)
}

div {
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This works very nicely on chrome, but not optimally on e.g. firefox. Do you know why? I removed the -webkit-, but the problem ramains.

Comment: @ravi what kind of issue your are having with FF? it's ok on my side

Comment: I suspect there was something else causing the issue on firefox. Nevertheless, your solution worked nicely! Thanks!